# Why did my header and footer links disappear after creating Magento_Theme?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.1.1

I copied vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/* to app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme and my header top.links and footer links all vanished!

Can someone please let me know why this is happening?

After doing more research, could it be because my theme's parent is Luma and not blank? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have copied the wrong folder to your theme .

Please Copy this folder to your theme.

`vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme` to `app/design/frontend/MyVendor/MyTheme/Magento_Theme`